# Best way to manage Custom Object layouts through API?

Tags: metadata-api, metadata, ruby, ruby-on-rails, page-layout

I have a Ruby on Rails application.  I am asking the user for the object name that they use for invoices, i.e. "Invoice__c".  With use of the metaforce gem the app creates the field "PDF_Link__c" on the object.  The problem is that it does not show up on the layout and the user will have to edit the layout manually to see the field.

I am hoping for a good way to update the layout at the same time the field is generated so the user can see the field automatically when they provide the name of the invoice object.

So far I can use describeLayout() to return a description of the layout in xml (metaforce converts it into an Hashie:Mash object which has to_xml, to_hash and a bunch of other cool methods).  I tried to use this response to update the layout but the problem with this is the response is it is different than what update what update expects.

Anyone have any advice on how to dynamically add this column to an existing layout?

Comment: in case you want to do it in apex here is the awesome post by awesome MVP [Andrew Fawcett] - http://andyinthecloud.com/2013/12/24/updating-layouts-in-apex/

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure on Ruby-specifics, but we manage a Java application that dynamically creates fields for an object and then also manages the Page Layout (according to our application-specific rules).  We use the `Salesforce Metadata API` to do all this.

Essentially, the Page Layout is just an `XML document`, so at worst, you'll have to code up a way to insert the new field(s) where you want it(them) in the XML document that is the Page Layout.  You can view the XML-Page-Layout via the **Eclipse IDE**.

Metadata API User's Manual:  http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/